# Positioning Facebook Like on a wordpress header with existing social icons

Tags: wordpress, positioning, facebook-likebox

I've just built a site in wordpress and have added some social icons in the header section of the template and managed to get them in the right position and all aligned in the top right hand corner.

I have now generated the facebook like button to incorporate but it seems to be totally misaligned and I don't know how to get it in position.

Please could someone advise. Sorry if this is a stupid question but I usually manage to get things straight after a bit of playing around but have failed on this occassion and been unable to find a way to do it that factors for my existing social icons or doesn't mess up my menu bar.

The code for the existing social icons is as follows:

```
    <div style="height:60px;"><section id="mysocial-menubar-99" class="widget       widget_social" style="padding-top:14px; text-align:right" >
<div class="social_wrap social_animation_fade komodomedia_32"><a href="http://dubaiartist.com/contact" rel="nofollow" target="_self"><img src="http://dubaiartist.com/wp-content/themes/striking/images/social/komodomedia_32/email_32.png" alt="Want to know more?Meer weten? Just contact us!" title="Want to know more? Just contact us!"/></a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/dubaiartist" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="http://dubaiartist.com/wp-content/themes/striking/images/social/komodomedia_32/facebook_32.png" alt="Follow us on Facebook" title="Follow us on Facebook"/></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/dubaiartist" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="http://dubaiartist.com/wp-content/themes/striking/images/social/komodomedia_32/twitter_32.png" alt="Follow us on twitter" title="Follow us on twitter"/></a></div </section></div>
```

Then I have the Facebook javascript code (generated by facebook) as follows:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And finally the code to place where I want the plugin to apper:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Thanks very much,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the section where you place your buttons you have :

```
</a></div </section></div>
```

You have an ending div that is not correctly closed, try :

```
</a></div> </section></div>
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I did that when I was having trouble posting to this site- the div is actually closed on there. I really need some way to position the like button. Currently it's overlaid on my header menu items. Thanks for your input

Comment: Is anyone else able to help at all please? Thanks so much.